# Locus of points on an argand diagram

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry, locus

I am having trouble with the following question. I am not asking domeone to explicitly solve it for me; just an indication of where I’m going wrong or an helpful insight is more than enough.

> Find the set of points, $z$, for which $\displaystyle\arg\left(\frac{z-i}{z+i}\right)=\pi/4$

Although I understand the question geometrically (finding points $z$ such that the angle between the vectors $z-i$ & $z+i$ is $45°$). I Have no idea at all on solving this geometrically.

Solving algebraically, I conclude that $z$ must lie on a circle of radius $\sqrt 2$ centered at $(-1,0)$. But the answer given only includes the **major arc** subtended by the segment joining $i$ & $-i$.

Where am I going wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and show us your algebraic solution, and we can point out for you where you made an error / flawed assumption. You can show us by clicking "Edit" beneath your question. (My guess, in advance, is that you took the square root of some negative real number without noticing it, or assumed that the square root of a positive real could be either positive or negative when for some reason the negative solutions shouldn't be considered.)

Comment: Probably you assumed that $\arg(x+iy)=\arctan(y/x),$ but this is true only for $x>0$

Comment: the argument of the complex number is 45 degrees, so it lies in the first quadrant. so if a and b are its real and imaginary parts, then the argument is infact arctan(b/a).

Comment: @JohnHughes I doubt I have made a numerical or algebraic error as the answer is the arc of the circle, whereas my (incoreect) answer is the full circle.  some geometrical reasoning must be required for the exclusion of the minor arc

Comment: Y'know, when you go to the doctor, you should generally tell the doctor your symptoms and let the **doctor** do the diagnosis. If you want to say "I'm sure there's no error in my algebra (which I decline to show you), even though it led to the wrong answer," you're going to have to find a different doctor.

Comment: I have posted the attempted solution. I dont know how to use the syntax and posting a picture seemed rather unprofessional for this site but there you go.

Comment: For future reference, a mathjax tutorial (or summary): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write
$$
\arg(x^2+y^2-1-2xi)=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
you don't know if the real part, $x^2+y^2-1,$ is or not positive, so you should set the condition
$$
x^2+y^2-1>0\tag1
$$
together with the condition that you already found
$$
x^2+y^2-1=-2x.\tag2
$$
The condition $(1),$ by using $(2)$ gives $-2x>0,$ or finally $x<0,$ so it excludes exactly the part of the circle required.

Comment: The (principal) argument of a complex number is acute only if its in the first quadrant, where the real part is in fact positve.

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH You should distinguish $(z-i)/(z+i)$ and $z.$
You know $\Re((z-i)/(z+i))=x^2+y^2-1>0,$ and this implies $\Re(z)=x<0,$ as explained in the answer.

Comment: ok. I see your point now. Had to draw the locus of  x2+y2−1>0  to see it. Thankyou for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is only major arc because then only the angle between the two vectors $z-i$ and $z+i$ is $45°$. On the minor arc, it will be $135°$ which is not desired. See this,

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think in the first case the angle is $180+45=225,$ the $360$ complement in the graphics.

Comment: @enzotib, in vectors it doesn't matter much.

Comment: It matters, because the sign of the tangent changes.

Comment: Oh, got it. Then it is equivalent to $-135°$.